# How can one update a class member/value from a function in c++

Tags: c++

I have a class representing a player. Separated into a header and a source like this.

```
#include "player.h"

player :: player(std::string name,int money,int position,int pcode)
       : name(name), money(money), position(position), pcode(pcode)
       {}

void player::setPlayer(std::string name,int money,int position,int pcode){
    name=name;
    money=money;
    position=position;
    pcode=pcode;
}

void player::setName(std::string name){
    name = name;
}

void player::setMoney(int money){
    money = money;
}

void player::setPosition(int position){
    position = position;
}

void player::setcode(int pcode){
    pcode = pcode;
}
```

header

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H_INCLUDED
#define PLAYER_H_INCLUDED
#include <string>

class player
{
private:
    std::string name;
    int money;
    int position;
    int pcode;
public:
    player(std::string name,int money=0,int position=0,int pcode=0);
    virtual void setPlayer(std::string name,int money,int position,int pcode);
    virtual void setName(std::string name);
    virtual void setMoney(int money);
    virtual void setPosition(int position);
    virtual void setcode(int code);
    std::string getName() { return name; }
    int getMoney() { return money; }
    int getCode()  { return pcode; }
    int getPosition()  { return position; }
    //players code
};

#endif // PLAYER_H_INCLUDED
```

I want to update the value of an instance of the player but it is not retaining the value, every iteration falls back to the initial declaration.
I have tried passing reference but it still doesn't work.

```
    void func_pos(CSquare squares[],player* me, player* opponent)
{
        int g;
        g = Random();//random generator func

        me->setPosition(10);

        std::cout<<me->getPosition()+g<<std::endl;
}
```

Function use

```
player car("Player 2", 1500, 0, 2);
player car("Player 2", 1500, 0, 2);
func_pos(squares, &dog, &car);
```

any assistance is appreciated

Comment: Why are you declaring a `player*` instead of a `player`?

Comment: The variable `me` is a pointer, but does it point somewhere valid? Please try to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: it is within another  function,, so i am passing the reference rather than the value

Comment: A hint: Think about the assignment `position = position`... What variable are you assigning to what variable?

Comment: Okay, then answer this: With `player* me`, what player object does `me` point to?

Comment: Don't give your parameters the same name as members of the class.

Comment: `name=name;`, `position=position;`, `money=money;` and `pcode = pcode;` -- none of this does what you think it does. What do you think this actually does, and why, exactly?

Comment: the goal was to attempt to update different items of the object independently

Comment: I was treating this as a named parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Giving a class member function's parameters the same name(s) as class data members is, IMHO, poor practice (although I see it a lot, here on Stack Overflow).

Consider your `setName` function:

```cpp
void player::setName(std::string name){
    name = name;
}
```

The code in this function doesn't change *anything* in the class instance on which it is called. Rather, it assigns the value of the given `name` string parameter to ... the given `name` string parameter. Thus, it achieves *nothing*.

If you *insist* on using such confusing parameter names, then you can disambiguate inside the function using the `this->` class pointer:

```cpp
void player::setName(std::string name){
    this->name = name;
}
```

However, I think it is far better to use different names for your parameters:

```cpp
void player::setName(std::string name_argument){
    name = name_argument;
}
```

You have (of course) similar issues in a number of your other class functions.

With compiler warnings *fully* enabled, you would readily spot these issues. For the `setName` function in your code, the MSVC compiler gives:

> warning C4458: declaration of 'name' hides class member

and clang-cl shows:

> warning : declaration shadows a field of 'player' [-Wshadow]
> warning : explicitly assigning value of variable of type 'std::string'
> (aka 'basic_string<char, char_traits, allocator >') to
> itself [-Wself-assign-overloaded]

Comment: Thank you. This was what i overlooked.