# Do I really need to overload the assignment operator here?

Tags: c++

I have this struct, with the following functions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

struct nod {
    std::pair<int, int> pozitieMatrice;
    nod* nodAnterior;

    nod() {};

    nod(std::pair<int, int> pozitieMatrice)
    {
        pozitieMatrice = pozitieMatrice;
        nodAnterior = nullptr;
    }

    nod(std::pair<int, int> pozitieMatrice, nod* nodAnterior)
    {
        pozitieMatrice = pozitieMatrice;
        nodAnterior = nodAnterior;
    }
};

void citirePozSoricelSiBranza(nod &nodInitial, nod &nodFinal)
{
    int x, y;
    std::cin >> x >> y;
    nodInitial = nod(std::pair<int, int>(x, y));
    std::cin >> x >> y;
    nodFinal = nod(std::pair<int, int>(x, y));
}

int main()
{
    int** matrice, n;
    nod nodInitial, nodFinal;
    citirePozSoricelSiBranza(nodInitial, nodFinal);
    return 0;
}
```

I get this error twice:

```
function "nod::operator=(const nod &) throw()" (declared implicitly) cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function
```

on these lines:

```
nodInitial = nod(std::pair<int, int>(x, y));
nodFinal = nod(std::pair<int, int>(x, y));
```

What is the solution? How can I fix it?

I'm thinking that I might need an assignment operator but I'm not really sure, because after all I only need to call the constructor on nodInitial and nodFinal, inside "citirePozSoricelSiBranza", but I'm not sure.

Comment: What compiler, version, and language standard are you compiling with?  [Code works fine here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/edf9f066ea5d84e7)

Comment: Is this the whole code of the structure `nod`?

Comment: @NathanOliver VS 2019, C++14, Windows 10

Comment: My crystal ball says that either your `nod` class has members that you're keeping from us, or your IntelliSense is acting up in its usual endearing manner.

Comment: @molbdnilo this was the minimal reproductive example. Here's the whole code: https://pastebin.com/N0JYqGPJ

Comment: [Works fine with that as well](https://godbolt.org/z/73PvEq).  Are you sure the code here matches the code you are compiling?

Comment: Not linked to the question but be careful, both class member variable and function param are called 'pozitieMatrice'!

Comment: @NathanOliver yes. I've just copied and pasted the code into my VS and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Make sure you have all of the includes that are required.  You have `iostream` and `queue`, but you also need `vector`, `utility`.  That might change things.

Comment: I'm sorry, it does compile, but it throws those errors.

Comment: Here's a print screen with the problems: I've also added vector and utility https://imgur.com/a/EVfH95H

Comment: So your compiler compiles it but your IDE highlights it as error? It's a false positive in IntelliSense or a wrong configuration for IntelliSense. Even pedantic GCC doesn't find anything: https://wandbox.org/permlink/t1oEmuZrVIGPkAIe

Comment: @jabaa yes. The program compiles it, but IntelliSense highilights an error.

Comment: IntelliSense gets it wrong from time to time.  Not sure if there is anything you can do to fix it.  Try searching *IntelliSense copy assignment operator error* or something like it.  You might find something.

Comment: @NathanOliver thanks a lot. I didn't even try to compile it, I've seen an error and I thought it won't work, but it actually did. That's the first time I'm getting this.

Comment: I don't know how Microsoft handles such problems but once I reported a false positive in Eclipse CDT and a week later a fixed version was released.

Comment: @jabaa should I do that myself?

Comment: The best feature of IntelliSense is that you can switch it off. It's particularly worthless for beginners, who obviously can't judge whether it's on to something or just on something.

Comment: You can wait until someone else does it but if your case is very special it will take much time. But first make sure that's a problem on their side. Create a [mcve] and add it to your report. It's possible that you'll find out this way that the problem is on your side.

Comment: Your two non-default constructors don't do what you think. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66482482/10871073) on why not.

Comment: @AdrianMole thanks for the heads up! :)